# Variable determines matrix dimension

Tags: matlab, matrix

Assume that I wish to define a matrix but the number of dimension of the matrix is a variable (v) in Matlab.

If v=1, then

M(1:10) = 0;

if v=2, then

M(1:10, 1:10) = 0;

...

I thought about how to use "reshape" to do this but I am scratching my head on how to do this exactly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For arbitrary `v`, you can use the vector-input form of [`zeros`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html). Because of how this function works, the input `v=1` needs special treatment if you want it to give a *row* vector (as seems to be the case from your code):

```
N = 10;
v = 3;
if v==1
    sz = [1 N]; % or [N 1] for column vector
else
    sz = repmat(N, 1, v);
end
M = zeros(sz);
```

Equivalently, if you prefer it in a single line:

```
M = zeros([repmat(1, 1, v==1) repmat(N, 1, v)]); % v=1 gives a row vector
```

or

```
M = zeros([repmat(N, 1, v) 1]); % v=1 gives a column vector
```

The latter works because Matlab arrays have an [infinite number of trailing singleton dimensions](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
switch v
    case 1
       M=zeros(1,10);%matrix of size 1,10
    case 2
       M=zeros(10,10);%matrix of size 10,10
end
```